# windows server 2008 r2: ensure that your web role has the 'management tools' option installed

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5

I installed web deploy 3.5 on my windows server 2008 R2 server. but Management server delegation seems  not installed. I found the answer on serverfault.

[Can not see "Management Service Delegation" option in IIS 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/128468/can-not-see-management-service-delegation-option-in-iis-7)

i need to ensure that your web role has the 'management tools' option installed.  what is my web role? where can i find it?